# How to break path expansion in SPARQL?

Tags: graph, sparql, rdf, triplestore, propertypath

Considering the following dataset I am trying to find all friends-of-friends but stop expanding the path as soon as one of the friends is e.g. a Lawyer.

[image]

```
:Ben :knows :Lena .
:Lena :knows :Grek .
:Grek :knows :John .
:John :knows :Bill .

:Ben :knows :Peter . 
:Peter :knows :Cece .
:Cece :knows :Joe .
:Joe :knows :Mike .

:Cece :profession :Lawyer .
```

The expected result is:

```
Ben, Lena, Grek, John, Bill, Peter
```

What I am doing now is:

```
SELECT ?friend
WHERE {
       :BEN :knows+ ?friend. 
       FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?friend ^:knows*/:profession :Lawyer}
      }
```

For bigger datasetes this is just way to slow and actually holds a lot of data in memory that is irrelevant.

Is it possible to cut the path expansion **instead of filtering the results afterwards**?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "cut" a property path expression like this in SPARQL.

Moreover, I don't think the query you are currently using does what you want. It will exclude any person who is known by a lawyer, regardless if the lawyer is on a path of :knows links from Ben. For example, if Alice was a lawyer, and Alice knew Bill, Bill would no longer be included in the results. I think this is a better query for what you describe:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>
SELECT ?friend WHERE {
    :Ben :knows+ ?friend.
    MINUS {
        :Ben :knows+ ?lawyer .
        ?lawyer :profession :Lawyer ; :knows* ?friend .
    }
}
```

Depending on the SPARQL system you are using, the use of `MINUS` instead of `FILTER NOT EXISTS` may also have better performance.

Comment: thanks gregory - just for clarification: is there any way to solve this then? AllegroGraph has Lisp as a native language but what about the others?

Comment: ans what systems like MINUS more than FILTER ?

Comment: My guess would be that almost all systems will perform a MINUS more efficiently than NOT EXISTS, but to what extent is entirely an implementation detail that would be hard to guess without benchmarking.

Comment: As to "solving," if the issue is just performance, I'd try the MINUS query and see how it works. It may be that what you're after is beyond your threshold for query performance. If that's the case, then your options include looking for a different SPARQL system that has different performance characteristics, implementing the query yourself using a lower-level API, or using a different query language (perhaps a traversal language like Gremlin would be better suited to your needs).